# Error "Expression must have a pointer to object type" in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a Boolean function to check if two unsorted arrays have the same elements. But every time I try to debug the program,I keep getting an error "Expression must have a pointer to object type". I have tried everything. Nothing seem to be working. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool haveSameElems(arr1, arr2, size);

void main()
{
    int size;

    scanf("%d", &size);
    int* arr1 = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &arr1[i]);
    }
    int* arr2 = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &arr2[i]);
    }

    bool ans = haveSameElems(arr1, arr2, size);

    printf("%s", ans ? "true" : "false");
}

bool haveSameElems(arr1, arr2, size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) // I keep getting the error here 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the prototypes you have not written the types of the arguments. It should be something like `bool haveSameElems(int *var1, int *var2, int size)`

Comment: Your function declaration and definition is wrong … you need to specify data types for your parameters! Furthermore, `main` must return `int`. Lastly, `haveSameElems` does not always return a value.

Comment: Also, your function is not doing what you say you want. Here, you will just check that at least your arrays have a common value, because you `return true`

Comment: @Veronika Kovaleva And where is there the recursive function?

Comment: Defining a function without type specifier is, unfortunately, accepted by actual compilers due to the compliance with old K&R grammar still accepted, and defaults the objects to `int` type. So while the function definition is still accepted when you try to use the `int` defaulted variables, `arr1` and `arr2`, as arrays the compiler triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration `bool haveSameElems(arr1, arr2, size)` is implicitly the same as `bool haveSameElems(int arr1, int arr2, int size)`, per [Frankie_C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542393/error-expression-must-have-a-pointer-to-object-type-in-c#comment105256216_59542393). To use `arr1` and `arr2` as arrays, they must be declared as pointers: `bool haveSameElems(int *arr1, int *arr2, int size)`. So you need to add those two asterisks in both the function declaration at the top of your code and in the function definition it corresponds to. It’s good practice *always explicitly* to write types and not rely on the old K&R style implicit `int` types Frankie_C wrote about in his comment. You can read more about it in the bottom box [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition) and in the “subscript” section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access).

You also [need](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return) a `return false` at the end of `haveSameElems`, and `main` must return type `int` if you’re using an older C complier. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).